# Database with product information

Tags: ruby, database, api

I would like to write a ruby script that pulls information about store products and organizes it. While I'm sure I have the programming knowledge to do this, I am not at all sure where this kind of information is made available via the web. Does anyone know of a database/api that exposes this kind of information. I would hate to have to write crawlers to crawl individual store websites and ..... parse HTML ......

Comment: this is related to programming, and the question was answered and complete. Closing.unnecessary? => true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Amazon Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html). It gives you access to the entire Amazon product catalog so it probably is the most extensive database you'll find out there.

Comment: thanks thats a great link! I'll be starting there. Do you know if there is a way to get data regarding specific stores such as wal-mart. I have noticed that best buy has an api, for example.

Comment: I don't know specifically about Walmart, it depends if they expose an API. I once had to query a famous sports retailer catalog but since they did not expose any API, I was forced to scrape their site using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) and [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/). If you choose to use the Amazon catalog, you may be interested in a client library such as [ruby/aws](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/ruby-aws/). Also you should probably double-check the terms of usage of the sites you're planning to use the catalog from.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, you've gotten me on my way.